# High Speed Serial (UART) communication is failing for 3M baud rate and above with Software Flow Control

Tags: serial-port, linux-device-driver, uart

I am working on `linux kernel 4.8` and have configured `ttyS2` to act as `HSUART` as shown in the dmesg log:

`[2.599632] dw-apb-uart.9: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x9232e000 (irq = 5, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A`

I am able to communicate through `ttyS2` successfully till `921800 baud rate` with `software flow control`, but for higher baud rates i.e `3M/4M` there is `FIFO overrun` at the receiver side. The `FIFO_SIZE` is `16 bytes` and I have tried configuring `RECEIVER_FIFO_THRESHOLD` to `8` and `14` `bytes` but still the issue persists. However there is no issue seen if I use `Hardware Flow Control` (`CTS` & `RTS`)

Any inputs on the maximum `baud rate` that can be used with `software flow control` for successful serial communication would definitely be of help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you probably meant `921600`. Second, the FIFO size there is 64 bytes, but threshold might be smaller. Third, I don't remember FIFO **overrun** there, rather **input underrun**. If it's the case, there are two factors that might  affect: IRQ latency and CPU/DMA latency.

Comment: I seriously believe that the `HSUART` implementation in Linux has an **architectural issue** as in when the `DMA` takes long time enough to handle the subsequent transfer and the input `FIFO` **overruns**. I am working on these lines to substantiate my findings. By the way, since you have already suggested some solutions, is this a known issue to you? Because I din't find any kernel bugs filed related to the same.

Comment: It has, but this will be last reason to get transfer abortions. You indeed can't get overrun there, it is **too much work for irq** message, which directly shows to the IRQ latency issue. For your interest the DMA issue  is being discussed in public mailing lists: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg22315.html

Comment: Not sure if we're talking about the same thing here. I am clearly seeing **input overrun(s)** in the dmesg logs:

Comment: Just to make sure that its not an `IRQ latency` issue, I moved the `IRQ` to use the other less `IRQ-intensive CPUs`, like:          `# echo '2' > /proc/irq/5/smp_affinity_list` but still there are **input overrun(s)** I also prevented `CPU` from entering `deep-C` states but the issue still persists. I don't think the issue is due to `CPU/DMA latency` **and** `IRQ latency` and until the **architectural bug in DMA** is fixed, we can't get lucky. I am working on solving the `DMA` bug currently.

Comment: Oh, my bad, that's true, the message is **input overrun(s)** indeed. Regarding to the issue itself I saw it exactly in case when CPU was in deep C state and there were not enough time to get the input handled properly.